# HTTP to HTTPS redirect on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a requirement wherein i need to redirect traffic from http to https however this i need to implement using : ingress.class: gce-internal.
As per my understanding GCP currently does not support this re-direction for gce-internal class.
Therefore, reaching out to the community to understand if there are some alternative ways of accomplishing the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GCP and the ingress.class: gce-internal for your Ingress resource, it's a correct that GCP does not support automatic redirection from HTTP to HTTPS for gce-internal class. However, there are alternative ways to accomplish the HTTP to HTTPS redirection within your application or infrastructure.
such as

-Handle redirection in your application

-Use a load balancer or reverse proxy

-Utilize external services